# Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, is not a valid identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, error-handling

I'm getting the following error:

> *Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Procedure getQuestion, Line 18*
>   The name 'select top(1) * from tlb_Question inner join tlb_options on tlb_options.qID=tlb_Question.id and tlb_Question.qNumber=1 and tlb_Question.id not in (0,1)' is not a valid identifier

from the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc getQuestion
    @qNo bigint,
    @total bigint,
    @next nvarchar(max)
as
begin 
    declare @hisa bigint
    set @hisa=@total/3

    if(@qNo<=@total/3)
    begin
    declare @query nvarchar(max)
    set @query=('select top(1) * from tlb_Question 
        inner join tlb_options on tlb_options.qID=tlb_Question.id and tlb_Question.qNumber=1 and tlb_Question.id not in ('+cast(@next as varchar)+')')
    print @query
    execute @query
    end
end
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please try this, changed execute @query to execute (@query):

```
ALTER proc getQuestion
    @qNo bigint,
    @total bigint,
    @next nvarchar(max)
as

begin 
    declare @hisa bigint
    set @hisa=@total/3

    if(@qNo<=@total/3)
    begin
      declare @query nvarchar(max)
      set @query=('select top(1) * from tlb_Question 
      inner join tlb_options on tlb_options.qID=tlb_Question.id and tlb_Question.qNumber=1 and tlb_Question.id not in ('+cast(@next as varchar)+')')
      --print @query
      execute (@query)
    end
end
```

Comment: why we need to write ``exec(@query)`` why ``exec @query`` not works

Comment: Not sure but I'm willing to bet it has to do with concatenation with the + symbol!!

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I have been banging my head against the wall all week long.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `execute @query`. I can confirm that after testing it out. @techdo was correct. Change it to

```
execute (@query)
```