# How to change a sql login password with variables

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to update the password for an existing SQL login using Alter LOGIN

I know the following works

```
ALTER LOGIN [username1] WITH PASSWORD = 'somenewpassword123';
```

However when I try to use a local variable

```
DECLARE @newpass nvarchar(max);
SET @newpass = 'P@ssw0rd12345';
ALTER LOGIN [username1] WITH PASSWORD = @newpass;
```

This fails. Adding [] braces to the variable seems to resolve this within the SSMS query editor however using this programmaticlly by writing out the query in C# it fails as the above statement with the same error ( syntax error at PASSWORD)

Code within c# app

```
public static int UpdateSqlLoginPassword(DbContext context, string loginName, string password)
{
 try
 {
  string updatePassword =
         @"  SET NOCOUNT ON
          DECLARE @loginName AS nvarchar(max) = {0}
          DECLARE @password AS nvarchar(max) = {1}
          EXEC('
          USE master
          ALTER LOGIN ['+ @loginName + '] WITH PASSWORD = ['+ @password + ']
          ')";
  return context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(updatePassword, loginName, password);
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {  
  return -2;
 }
}
```

I have also tried to hash the password (thinking that was the issue with the variable) but the syntax here is not being accepted

```
DECLARE @newpass nvarchar(max);
SET @newpass = 'P@ssw0rd12345';
DECLARE @hashedpass varbinary(max);
SET @hashedpass = HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@newpass));

ALTER LOGIN [newuser10] WITH PASSWORD = @hashedpass HASHED;
SELECT @hashedpass;
```

Can anyone help me understand how to update a login's password in sql using a variable instead of a fixed value?

thanks in advance

**Update**

Based upon a suggestion from Charlie I also tried the following

```
public static int UpdateSqlLoginPassword(DbContext context, string loginName, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                string updatePassword =
                    @"ALTER LOGIN [' + @loginName +'] WITH PASSWORD =  @password ";
                return context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(updatePassword, new SqlParameter("loginName", loginName), new SqlParameter("password", password));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {  
               return -2;
            }
        }
```

This still generates a sqlException Incorrect Syntax new '@password'. 
If I brace the parameter

```
public static int UpdateSqlLoginPassword(DbContext context, string loginName, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                string updatePassword =
                    @"ALTER LOGIN [' + @loginName +'] WITH PASSWORD =  [' + @password +']";
                return context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(updatePassword, new SqlParameter("loginName", loginName), new SqlParameter("password", password));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {  
               return -2;
            }
        }
```

I then generate a sqlException Incorrect syntax near PASSWORD.

**Update2**

Using the updated suggestions from Charlie I attempted to use the QuoteName function

```
        string sql = @"DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
              SET @sql = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + QuoteName(@loginName) +
                ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QuoteName(@password, '''') 
                EXEC @sql";
        return context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, new SqlParameter("loginName", loginName), new SqlParameter("password", password));
```

While it appears that the query string is properly formed the following SQLException is thrown
*The name 'ALTER LOGIN [newuser10] WITH PASSWORD = 't#P@ssw0rd'' is not a valid identifier.

**EDIT**

After some more reading the error was generated by a syntax error wrapping the @sql allows the query to execute with no errors

```
 string sql = @"DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
                  SET @sql = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + QuoteName(@loginName) +
                    ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QuoteName(@password, '''') 
                    EXEC(@sql)";
```

On a side note: by simply building the string and running it as

```
string updatePassword = "USE MASTER ALTER LOGIN [" + loginName + "] WITH PASSWORD =  '" + password + "'";
return context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(updatePassword);
```

the above is also a workaround and updates the sql login. While the implementation of this code minimizes the potential for sql injections this is not the most desirable approach.

-Thanks

Comment: How exactly is it failing?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: yes from a sql query window if you just run the ALTER LOGIN [username] with PASSWORD = @newpass; the error "Incorrect syntax new 'newpass' is generated. Running the code block above in c# catches the same exception as it is bubbling up from the sql query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use parameters at the `DbContext` level. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474264/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-dbcontext-database-executesqlcommand-method) for more details, but, here's a code example (adapted from that same page):

```
string sql = "ALTER LOGIN @loginName WITH PASSWORD = @password";
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    sql,
    new SqlParameter("loginName", loginName),
    new SqlParameter("password", password));
```

The purpose of using the parameters here (and everywhere) is to prevent a SQL injection attack. This is especially important given that you are writing code that changes a password.

**UPDATE**

The ALTER LOGIN statement won't work with variables; it must be done through dynamic SQL. Here's an example of the updated code:

```
string sql = @"DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
               SET @sql = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + QuoteName(@loginName) + 
                    ' WITH PASSWORD= ' + QuoteName(@password, '''') 
               EXEC @sql ";
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    sql,
    new SqlParameter("loginName", loginName),
    new SqlParameter("password", password));
```

Note we're still using the SqlParameters to prevent SQL injection attacks. We are also using the T-SQL method [QuoteName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474264/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-dbcontext-database-executesqlcommand-method) to do proper quoting in the SQL we are generating; but this method simply doubles any `[` characters (in the first call) or `'` characters (in the second). There are many other vectors for a SQL injection attack, so merely relying on `QuoteName` wouldn't be enough.

Comment: sp_password is noted as being removed in a future version of SQL Server and they point you to use ALTER LOGIN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174428.aspx.  I only know cause I went there first ;)

Comment: Ha! I did not realize that. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Charlie I will give this a try I was avoiding the sp_password based on it being deprecated out in the future. I know that will be a ways out but I was following the suggestions of MSDN

Comment: @CharlieKilian Still getting the same sqlException incorrect syntax near password. I update my original question with your suggestion for reference.

Comment: I was afraid that might happen. Give me a sec, I'll post an update.

Comment: @CharlieKilian Any ideas on this one I Used QuoteName as you suggested but it is throwing the following exception The name 'ALTER LOGIN [newuser10] WITH PASSWORD = 't#P@ssw0rd'' is not a valid identifier. I have updated my original question for more detail.

Comment: That is interesting, because I tested that code before I posted it to make sure it worked. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: With more thought on it today, what I wonder is, if you paste the SQL statement into SQL Server Management Studio, does the statement work?

Comment: I needed to put the EXEC parameter in brackets to make this work: `EXEC (@sql)`

Comment: The link doesnt say anything about QuoteName, probably wrong link

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the above answer with Azure SQL and I was getting the "not a valid identifier" error until I surrounded replaced "EXEC @sql" with "EXEC (@sql)". See [Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, is not a valid identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205827/msg-203-level-16-state-2-is-not-a-valid-identifier)

Additionally, I had to use "ALTER USER" instead of "ALTER LOGIN"

Answer (score 0):

After Preparing SQL query string and executing using c# SQL Command, I was always getting Invalid Identifier error.
It was because **QuoteName** should get executed before executing change password sql statements.
So I created stored procedure using above solutions then called procedure from c#, it worked for me.

```
Create procedure usp_updateSqlUsers(@loginName nVarchar(100), @pwd nvarchar(100))
as
 begin
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500) 
set @sql='Alter LOGIN  '+QUOTENAME(@loginName)+' WITH 
  password=N'+ QUOTENAME(@pwd,'''')
  exec sp_sqlexec @sql

 end
```

Then execute from C#

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_updateSqlUsers", con) {CommandType = 
 CommandType.StoredProcedure};
 var passwordParam = new SqlParameter("@pwd", password);
 var sqlLoginParameter = new SqlParameter("@loginName", "SqlLoginName");
 cmd.Parameters.Add(passwordParam);
 cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlLoginParameter);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```