# Change MS SQL Login Password in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication, alter

I'm trying to change passwords of SQL server logins, but the Passwords just won't change.
This is what I have:

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("ALTER LOGIN @login WITH PASSWORD = '@Pwd'", con);
query.Parameters.Add("@login", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60).Value = login;
query.Parameters.Add("@Pwd", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = _newPwds[login];
query.Prepare();
query.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
```

I don't get any error messages back from the SQL Server or debugging (Or I don't know how to get them). The Connection is correct and I have the rights to Change Passwords on the Server (Application is running with Integrated Security).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mason Thanks, didn't know that. I changed it and now I get "Incorrect Syntax near '@login'".

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858034/how-to-change-a-sql-login-password-with-variables) for an example of using parameters with an alter login statement.

Comment: @mason Thanks! I'll test that on Thursday, but I think this will do. Could you add this to your answer? Then I would mark it as the right answer after I tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an asynchronous method [BeginExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) to execute the query, so you haven't captured it. Given you probably didn't want to go async, try using [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
query.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Plus you can't use parameters in an ALTER LOGIN statement, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14858034/5409929).